# Can't enable OpenGL in LibreOffice 5.0+

Tags: nvidia, libreoffice, opengl

I'm trying to enable OpenGL rendering in LibreOffice and I can't seem to be able to.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 , Nvidia GTX960 , and Nvidia drivers 367.57.

[image: OpenGL]

Symptoms:

When OpenGL is enabled (top option) the application just crashes with a cryptic error:
`soffice.bin crashed with SIGSEGV in OpenGLContext::AcquireFramebuffer()`

When I pick the second option (even if blacklisted) the application won't start at all.

Is there a solution to this and what could be preventing OpenGL from being enabled?

Comment: It looks like as bug to me, here is a similar case reported https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1641264 , related upstream bug report https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=97160 . Here is the debug help doc if you want to check it your self and you may update the report with needed info requested by developer https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/QA/BugReport/Debug_Information

Comment: It does seem like it's a bug. I was told by a libreoffice developer to turn on my OpenGL to fix a font rendering issue but the application kept crashing. I wonder if there is a workaround.

Comment: can you upgrade LibreOffice?